# Segmentaion fault on memory allocation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have two function `open_files` and `read_bytes`. When I only call `open_files` everything works as it should but if I call `read_bytes` after, I get an segmentation fault in `open_files`. I use gcc as a compiler.

`open_files` is a function that look trough a directory and populates a struct containg the filename and length of char array.

`read_bytes` is a function with no code and only returns 1.

The struct for filenames

```
struct file_name{
    char * name;
    int length;
};
```

The main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct file_name ** files;
    int file_length;
    unsigned char * hex;
    long int bytesLength;
    printf("CRAP");
    getchar();
    //Function open_files works if read_bytes function is not called....
    if(open_files(files, &file_length) >= 0){
        printf("CRAP2");
        getchar();
        if (read_bytes(hex, &bytesLength, files[0]->name) >= 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < bytesLength; ++i){
                printf("%X\n",hex[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Something went wrong");
    }

    printf("%s\n", "Helluuuuuu");

    free_memory(files, file_length);

    return 0;
}
```

The `open_files` function creates a file_name struct for each file in a directory.

```
int open_files(struct file_name ** files, unsigned int * length){
    DIR * dir;
    struct dirent * ent;
    int count = 0;
    if((dir = opendir("TestFiles")) != NULL){

        while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL ){
            ++count;

        }
        count -= 2;
        closedir(dir);
    }
    else{
        //Couldn't open directory
        perror("");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("working");
    getchar();
    //Allocate memory
    *files = malloc(count * sizeof(struct file_name *));
    printf("not working");
    getchar();
    *length = count;

    if((dir = opendir("TestFiles")) != NULL){
        count = 0;
        while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL ){
            if(strcmp(ent->d_name,".") != 0 && strcmp(ent->d_name,"..") != 0){
                struct file_name * file = malloc(sizeof(struct file_name));
                file->name = malloc(strlen(ent->d_name));
                strcpy(file->name,ent->d_name);
                file->length = strlen(ent->d_name);
                files[count] = file;
                ++count;
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    else{
        //Couldn't open directory
        perror("");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `read_bytes` is an empty function that returns 1:

```
int read_bytes(unsigned char * hex, long int * length, char * file){
    //FILE * fp;
    //*length = file_size(file);
    //printf("%li\n",*length );

    //fp = fopen("TestFiles/first.jpg", "r");
    //fread(hex, 1, *length, fp);
    //fclose(fp);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `file->name = malloc(strlen(ent->d_name));` --> `file->name = malloc(strlen(ent->d_name)+1);`  (+1)  Maybe other  issues too.

Comment: bytesLength contains garbage as far as I think. you are not storing any value and passing it to for loop.

Comment: @chux I added +1 and still segmentation fault

Comment: @Mazhar It's planned that bytesLength will gets its value from the read_bytes function.

Comment: Creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make this far easier to determine the cause of, not just for you but for those attempting to help you. Furthermore, problems like this can usually be easily resolved by using a debugger. Have you tried that already? Lastly, heed any compiler warnings that happen when you compile your program - trying to compile this, GCC gives many warnings and even an error. If you're not getting warnings or errors when compiling, you should switch to a compiler that shows them.

Comment: You're passing `open_files()` an uninitialised pointer-to-pointer from `main()` (`files`), then trying to set *what it points to* to point to a newly allocated block of memory.  That may cause an access violation, and if it didn't the pointer still wouldn't be available in `main()`.  (hint: pass the address of a pointer from `main()`, instead of the value of (an uninitialised) pointer-to-pointer)

Comment: There are a number of other issues as well... for example you call `read_bytes()` for the first entry without checking the number of entries `open_files()` returned (what happens for an empty directory, where `open_files()` succeeds but with 0 file names?)... and you don't handle the case where new files are created in the directory between your `opendir()` to get the count and the `opendir()` to read the filenames...

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
*files = malloc(count * sizeof(struct file_name *));
```

to allocate your pointer array which is not correct. An array of struct pointers would have type `struct file_name **` but you assign it to a `struct file_name *`·

Then you do:

```
files[count] = file;
```

For `count == 0` that overwrites the address returned by `malloc()` (`files[0] == *files`), for `count > 0` it invokes Undefined behaviour.

You could either pass a `struct file_name ***` to `open_files()` and change

```
files[count] = file;
```

to

```
(*files)[count] = file;
```

or allocate an array of structs:

```
 *files = malloc(count * sizeof(struct file_name) );  
 ....
        if(strcmp(ent->d_name,".") != 0 && strcmp(ent->d_name,"..") != 0){
            struct file_name * file = (*files) + count;  // struct is already allocated (alternatively: &((*files)[count])
            file->name = malloc(strlen(ent->d_name)+1);
            strcpy(file->name,ent->d_name);
            file->length = strlen(ent->d_name);
            ++count;
        }
```

In `main()`, you must pass `&files` to `open_files()` in both cases. 
If you choose the second solution, please change

```
struct file_name ** files;
```

to

```
struct file_name * files;
```

and

```
files[0]->nam
```

to

```
files[0].name
```

Please notice `file->name = malloc(strlen(ent->d_name)+1);` which is neccessary in both cases as already mentioned

Comment: @alk you're right of course, I've only looked at the function itself. Added it, thanx

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt On the line `struct file_name * file = &files[count];  // struct is already allocated` I get a: `warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                 struct file_name * file = &files[count];  // struct is already`